# Is there an alternative to View.GetOutline() which gives a better outline?

Tags: vba, solidworks

Outline returned by `View.GetOutline()` method does not quite correspond to the visible drawing - it returns a bit more than the selection outline shown by SolidWorks GUI.

The screenshot below shows the selection outline (light blue dotted rectangle) and diagonal of the outline returned by `View.GetOutline()` (red line):

[image]

**Is there a way to get bounding box that corresponds to the actually visible drawing?**

***Note:** Original title of this question was "Is there an alternative to View.GetOutline() which does NOT include Temporary Axes?", however I discovered that **`View.GetOutline()` actually does not include** Temporary Axes. The problem was in the **`View.Position`** property which defines center bounding box that **includes Temporary Axes**.

Artem's answer was quite useful so I decided to change the question to correspond to the answer and post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649808/is-there-an-alternative-to-view-getoutline-which-does-include-temporary-axes) for the actual problem.*

Answer (score 3):

You can get the bounding box from underlying model via IPartDoc::GetBox/IAssemblyDoc::GetBox API and transform this to a view space via IView::ModelToViewTransform as shown in [this example](https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-api/document/drawing/sheet-context-sketch/).

You will only need the following portion of code form the DrawBBoxDiagonal function if you do not want to draw the diagonal. The values of vStartPt and vEndPt are the end points of bounding box.

```
Dim vBox As Variant
Dim swViewTransform As SldWorks.MathTransform

Dim swMathPt As SldWorks.MathPoint
Dim vStartPt As Variant
Dim vEndPt As Variant

vBox = GetViewRefModelBBox(view)
Set swViewTransform = GetViewToSheetTransform(draw, view)

Dim swMathUtils As SldWorks.MathUtility
Set swMathUtils = swApp.GetMathUtility

Dim dPt(2) As Double
dPt(0) = vBox(0): dPt(1) = vBox(1): dPt(2) = vBox(2)

Set swMathPt = swMathUtils.CreatePoint(dPt)
Set swMathPt = swMathPt.MultiplyTransform(swViewTransform)
vStartPt = swMathPt.ArrayData

dPt(0) = vBox(3): dPt(1) = vBox(4): dPt(2) = vBox(5)

Set swMathPt = swMathUtils.CreatePoint(dPt)
Set swMathPt = swMathPt.MultiplyTransform(swViewTransform)
vEndPt = swMathPt.ArrayData
```

I would also recommend to get precise bounding box via IBody2::GetExtremePoint as shown [here](https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-api/geometry/precise-bounding-box/)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the examples before you edited the comment. The draw-diagonal example draws it over the same bounding box as returned by `GetOutline()` - it does not contain calls to 'ModelToViewTransform' method.

Comment: OK, so `ModelToViewTransform()` is used in the example after all, I must have misspelled it in the search. I'm checking it out in detail ...

Comment: Bingo! This actually seems to do the trick. However, the solution is not so obvious and marking this as the answer (as it is now) would not be really it. Can you edit the answer and add the needed code, please? I'll accept it then.

Comment: To make it easier for you: in the draw-diagonal example, in the `Sub DrawBBoxDiagonal()` replace the line `vBox = GetViewRefModelBBox(view)' with `vBox = view.Bodies(0).GetBodyBox()'. It will draw the diagonal across the visible drawing.

Comment: Well, it actually **fully** worked only the first time I run it. After that it draws the diagonal of correct proportions but **offset** to the drawing (sometimes also throws error _"The object invoked has disconnected from its clients."_). Not sure what is going on but since the proportions are OK it will work good enough for me.

Comment: Do you get the 'The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.' when you added this line?

vBox = view.Bodies(0).GetBodyBox()

Comment: Yes @Artem, but it is not consistent - it does not happen with freshly loaded macro/VBA IDE, only after a few runs. The line itself does not trigger it - if I use a different variable, e.g .Vbox2 and **not** use (keep using Vbox) it then the error does not popup. It is odd. However, it happens at the `draw.SketchManager.CreateLine` statement so it does not bother me as I do not need that.

Comment: The `GetViewRefModelBBox()` gets the **whole multibody part** bounding box which also includes all the temporary axes - you must get only the bounding box for **bodies contained by the view**. That is why I suggested the `vBox = view.Bodies(0).GetBodyBox()` statement (which assumes only one body). The only problem is, as I said, that the **resulting bounding box is offset** from the drawing view.

Comment: I just discovered that it is not `GetOutline()` that includes the temporary axes - it is **bounding box whose center is used for `View.Position` property**! So, I actually asked a wrong question, lol! I will edit the question to reflect that but likely not sooner than Monday (have no time). Artem, your answer is fine in that context too, just needs the correction I mentioned. I'll accept it after I correct the question.

Comment: I changed the question to correspond to your answer and posted a new one - please check it out. If you don't mind I can edit your answer regarding `GetViewRefModelBBox()` getting bounding box for the whole part instead of the single body.