# Is there an alternative to View.GetOutline() which DOES include Temporary Axes?

Tags: vba, solidworks

**Note:** This is **not** answered by the [suggested question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606697/is-there-an-alternative-to-view-getoutline-which-gives-a-better-outline) - it is practically the opposite of it. Besides, it is me who asked that question too and **I also linked to it below**.

I am fixing someone else's VBA code for SolidWorks which places drawing views next to each other based on their size.
Size of a view is taken from bounding box returned by `View.GetOutline()` and view's position is set by changing `View.Position` property.
The code processes multibody parts, creating one drawing sheet per body.

The **problem is that `View.Position` property corresponds to center of bounding box that includes Temporary Axes while `View.GetOutline()` does not include them** - it returns a bit more than the selection outline shown by SolidWorks GUI.

This is the multibody part and one of the offending drawing views with temporary axes turned on in the SW GUI:

[image: multibody part]   [image]

In the drawing you can see:

- selection outline shown by SW GUI (light blue dotted rectangle)
- diagonal of the outline returned by `View.GetOutline()` (red line)
- center of the view as in `View.Position` property (red X)
- temporary axes (blue crosses and lines)

**Is there a way to get drawing view's *real* size, the one that correspond to the bounding box whose center is the `View.Position` property?**

Apparently, the drawing view **includes temporary axes from other bodies** in this multibody part.
That points to the alternative question: **Is there a way to prevent temporary axes from other bodies in a multibody part from being included in drawing view of a single body?**

For reference, the problem is the same no matter which method is used to create the view (e.g. `CreateDrawViewFromModelView3()`, `CreateUnfoldedViewAt3()`, `CreateRelativeView()`, etc.).

*Note: I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606697/is-there-an-alternative-to-view-getoutline-which-gives-a-better-outline) that stems from this same problem which I changed because I wrongly assumed that `View.GetOutline()` does not include Temporary Axes.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an alternative to View.GetOutline() which gives a better outline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606697/is-there-an-alternative-to-view-getoutline-which-gives-a-better-outline)

Comment: Thanks @Anna, but that is also a question I asked, the one I linked to in this question. The link changed as I changed the title bu it is the same question.

Comment: To recieve correct real size of multibody assembly I use `GetBox` and `GetPartBox` function. But when there are multiconfiguration assemby there was an error in Solidworks to correct determination of drawview center you need sometimes manualy correction position of drawviews.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, I'm not sure I follow you. I have single body Views there and I **can** get the center of the View. What I **cannot** get is the outline of the View, the outline whose center is View.Position.

Comment: I calculate size of view, size of sheet, scale factor. By this value define View.position and assign it to View

Comment: @Ivan, How do you calculate size of a View? `GetOutline()` gives visible drawing "size", `View.Position` is **not** always center of that outline - that is the problem.

Comment: I obtained real size by `GetBox` or `GetPartbox`, and set scale factor, multiplicate it. Result is size of View. About of `View.Position`, can I obtain your SolidWorks file to open it and run my program on your file

Comment: Now I use `GetOutLine` function on my own example get very strange result!

Comment: @Ivan, you found out what I'm talking about - `GetOutline()` does not do what you'd expect it to. I'm not allowed to give you the files unfortunately. You can reproduce the behavior by making a multibody part with features that use temporary axes.

Comment: I'm not need use this function in my applcation. I knew about this strange behevior. I had explained my way to give correct result of  view size whithout of  offset from the drawing view. Then I calculate view position and assign it. I knew that assign position calculated by simple way (draw size, view size, distance between view) give not correct result. In my variant it was conserned with changing scale. I  had changed simple way formula to formula that use two centers of view (center in old scale and center in new scale). I don't use  temporary axes in models.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to do that.

Yesterday I had the same problem and I've fixed the issue.

As you correctly have stated there is an offset between the Bouding Box center on the drawing and the View center (whose coordinate are given by the View.Position property in VBA).

Actually you want to place the your view according the Bounding Box (BB) center (let's call this position DesiredBBPos)...but we have to set the position through View.Position property.

So what you have to do is just to get this offset before moving the view.
The **offset** is the **difference between** the **View center point (View.Position(0) ; View.Position(1))** and the **BB center ((Xmax+Xmin)/2 ; (Ymax+Ymin)/2 )**

I have defined an array Offset(1) in which I've put the Horizontal Offset and Vertical Offset (as above)

Now you can set the view position by a formula that will look like:

**View.Position (0) = DesiredBBPos(0) + Offset(0)**

**View.Position (1) = DesiredBBPos(1) + Offset(1)**

It works ;)

Aldo

Comment: Thanks Aldo but unfortunately I do not have access to a SW instance where I could verify your solution any more. If somebody else can verify this I will accept your answer.